# Android fixed tabs indicator width

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-tabs

I am developing a app that uses fixed tabs (exactly 2). The problem I have when using just 2 tabs is that the tab indicator (the blue stripe) is too short on both sides. Here is a example app:

[image]

The indicator is a few pixels short on the left side (same happens on the right when I switch tabs). I guessing this is some style problem, anyone know how to fix it? When I use 3 or more tabs the problem does not exist!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a lot of people use a third-party support library called [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) to help them with issues like this. I haven't given it a try yet, but it seems like it would help address your issue.

Comment: 1. Tried it...same result 2. ABS is now obsolete since ActionBar support was added in the v18 support library!